# Change div background specific for the div

Tags: javascript, background-image, onmouseover

I need help making a script for my project.

This is how the code looks like.

```js
var thumbnails = document.getElementsByClassName("thumbnail");
var thumbnails_lenght = thumbnails.length;

for(var i=0; i<thumbnails_lenght; i++) {
 thumbnails[i].onmouseover = function() {
  //The problem part
 };
 thumbnails[i].onmouseout = function(){
  
 };
}
```

```css
*{
 margin: 0 auto;
 font-family: sans-serif;
}
.item{
 width: 240px;
 height: 240px;
 margin: 5px;
 background: #EEE;
}
.thumbnail{
 width: 240px;
 height: 200px;
 background: #DDD;
}
.description{
 width: 240px;
 height: 40px;
 line-height: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
 <div class="thumbnail" id="1"></div>
 <div class="description">test</div>
</div>
```

I need to make it so when hover over div with specific class thumbnail to get the id of the thumbnail, every thumbnail div will have it's id and i need to get that number.

Comment: Your title says you want one thing and your question asks for a different thing. Are you trying to change the color of a div or get the ID of an element?

Comment: Actually, after i get the id i'm gonna change the div's backgroud image by the id.

Comment: You know you can change the background of elements while hovering over them with just css, right?

Comment: I know that but im gonna make it change multiple times.

Comment: 1 images is without hovering 2nd image is with hovering 3rd image is while hovering 2 secs and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var thumbnails = document.getElementsByClassName("thumbnail");
var thumbnails_lenght = thumbnails.length;

for(var i=0; i<thumbnails_lenght; i++) {
 thumbnails[i].onmouseover = function(event) {
  // You can get the id from the event passed to the handler:
        alert('The id is: ' + event.target.id);
 };
 thumbnails[i].onmouseout = function(){
  
 };
}
```

```css
*{
 margin: 0 auto;
 font-family: sans-serif;
}
.item{
 width: 240px;
 height: 240px;
 margin: 5px;
 background: #EEE;
  float: left;
}
.thumbnail{
 width: 240px;
 height: 200px;
 background: #DDD;
}
.description{
 width: 240px;
 height: 40px;
 line-height: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
 <div class="thumbnail" id="1"></div>
 <div class="description">test 1</div>
</div>
<div class="item">
 <div class="thumbnail" id="2"></div>
 <div class="description">test 2</div>
</div>
<div class="item">
 <div class="thumbnail" id="3"></div>
 <div class="description">test 3</div>
</div>
```

Your event handler will receive an event object. That object will have a "target" property which is the element that triggered the event. You can get the ID from event.target. I've modified your code to alert the ID.

Comment: Nice one but I will have multiple items, and when i hove over the specific one.

Comment: event.target will be the specific one.

Comment: I've updated the code to demonstrate on multiple items.